# Click Event Listener Being Dropped When Adding New Divs Dynamically

Tags: javascript, getelementbyid, addeventlistener

I'm adding divs to a parent div in plain javascript when a users selects a photo. I'm also adding two click events for opening a preview and for delete the photo. When the first photo is added, both events work fine, but when I add another photo, the newest photos has the click events, but the previous div(s) does not.

Why is this happening, and more importantly, how can I prevent it?

The code in question is below.

```js
function addImageToView(imageURI){
                var imageDiv = document.getElementById('imageMaster');
                imageDiv.innerHTML += '<div style="padding-bottom: 10px;"><div style="float: left;" class="thumbnail" id= img_'+ imageCounter +'><img id= img_'+ imageCounter +' src="' + imageURI + '"></div><div id= img_'+ imageCounter +'_delete>delete</div><div style="width:67%; padding-top: 30px; padding-left: 10px;" class="thumbnail"><label class="item item-input" id="article-input8"><input type="text" placeholder="Photo Caption" ng-model="data.report_title"></label></div></div>';
                document.getElementById('img_'+ $scope.imageCounter).addEventListener("click", function(){showMe(imageURI)});
                document.getElementById('img_'+ $scope.imageCounter + '_delete').addEventListener("click", function(){removePhoto(this, imageURI)});
            }
```

Comment: `imageDiv.innerHTML += ...` doesn't append elements to`imageDiv`, it replaces all existing elements with new elements, and the previously set event listeners are gone. To add elements to an existing element by adding a HTML string, you need to use [insertAdjacentHTML](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/insertAdjacentHTML).

Comment: Excellent. Thanks so much @Teemu. I didn't know that method existed. If you change your comment to an answer, I'll gladly accept it :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like @Teemu pointed out in the above comment, the innerHTML method completely replaces the element, and only the listeners I was afterwards remained. Using the insertAdjacentHTML method resolved it.